# How often to refresh Access Tokens in Auth0 when making requests

Tags: reactjs, next.js, auth0, auth0-js

I'm setting up my API to expect a valid token from auth0 on each request. I'm using `auth0-js` and am confused about how to use `checkSession()` which is listed here: https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js

```
  const authLink = setContext(async () => {
    let token;
    try {
      await auth.checkSession();
      auth.isAuthenticated
      token = auth.getAccessToken();
    } catch (e: any) {
      if (e.error !== "login_required" && e.error !== "consent_required") {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    return {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
      },
    };
  });
```

I'm currently running `checkSession()` on every request, which makes a call out to auth0's authorization server and ensures the token being sent with the request is valid and up to date.

This seems like overkill though and slows down requests pretty significantly. I would *think* that I could store the access token and only refresh it when it either wasn't set or has expired. Are there any issues with this? Most references I find using this library always seem to call `checkSession` before sending a request.

Answer (score 0):

It's encouraged to [store tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/security-guidance/data-security/token-storage) and only renew when necessary - This is generally referred to as [silent auth](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/login/configure-silent-authentication). Auth0 SPA SDKS for example take care of this for you with refresh tokens for the most part.